# Jboss xml parser conflict with xerces

Tags: web-services, spring, jboss, xml-parsing, jax-ws

I just figure out that there is a conflict with Jboss and xerces jar file when I try to deploy a spring web service(jax-ws) application. This is the error.

```
09:58:50,852 ERROR [JBossContextConfig] XML error parsing: context.xml
org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBRuntimeException: Failed to create a new SAX parser
```

After going through some technical forums, found out that this is a bug in jboss server.
Here is the [link](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/WhydoigetjavalangClassCastExceptionorgapachexercesparsersXIncludeAwareParserConfigurationinAS-5) to that bug report. It says remove the xercec.jar from the lib folder.

But if I remove the xerces jar, server gives a spring error because I think my application need that xcerces jar to parse some specific xml sysntaxes in applicationContext.xml. This is the spring error.

```
09:14:38,175 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context 
initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 
'com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.SpringBinding#0 defined in ServletContext 
resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)'
of type [org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService] while setting bean property 
'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object
creation; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when     
resolving field "DATETIME" the class loader (instance of 
org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the referring class, 
javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeConstants, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) 
for the field's resolved type, loader constraint violation: when resolving field 
"DATETIME" the class loader
```

It contains following xml sysntax.

```
<wss:service>
        <ws:service bean="#helloWs"/>
</wss:service>
```

I think server throws that spring error because jboss xml parser couldn't able to identify this specific xml sysntax which involve to create spring inner bean.(bean="#helloWs"). So I think overrides existing Jboss xml parser with xercess xml parser will do the trick. My question is how to do it? Any alternative suggestions for this issue are also welcome.

Thanks all in advance.

FYI: Same application works smoothly(without any modifications) in glassfish server 3.x :) But I need to deploy this in Jboss server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced this problem. In my case, solutions was to remove Xerces from my application but you need it.

An alternative solution to "removing xercers from your application" can be found [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-application-server/223-solving-jboss-5-classloading-issues.html).

Comment: Hi, I tried alternative solution and did the class loading configurations. Now I'm getting that spring inner bean exception. I have implemented the same app using xfire plugin and its working. I don't know what's the reason for this error. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: finally i found the solution for that spring error. I have removed some additional jars from the lib directory.(                   jaxen-1.1-beta-9
stax-api-1.0.1
stax-api-1.0-2
stax-utils-20040917
wsdl4j-1.6.1
xbean-2.2.0
xercesImpl
xmlParserAPIs-2.2.6.2
XmlSchema-1.1) Now its working :) thanks for the tip!